# Getting xml from other applications in android.

Tags: android, xml

I have two applications, can i get the complete xml file of application 1 in application 2 ? 
I am currently getting the individual resources application 1 in application 2 by using package manager.

Answer (score 0):

So my first suggestion is to just re-make the xml file in the second application.

However, I am assuming that since you are getting resources from the other application that you want to be able to interact with the second app, in which case I would suggest reading through the Android documentation on Intents:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share xml data you would need to create a content provider for this purpose.